# Cant Install wordpress plugins - freeze page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plugins

Im trying to install some plugins of a purchased wordpress theme

I did it successfully on my local host after increasing limit size and file size in `.htaccess` with the following code

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 1800
php_value max_input_time 180
```

but I cant install them on my hosted server and I tried to edit `wp-config` to add this line

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

and still no success

It shows unpacking the package... and browser keep spinning till it stops and the page freeze

or shows unpacking the package ....
installing the package ...

and same story, keep spinning till it stops

Ive searched a a lot, people suggested to install them manually but the package I purchased doesnt have separate plugins with it

Also, I dont have any `php.ini` on my wordpress directory on server

**EDIT**

---

I created `php.ini` file and wrote these lines

```
memory_limit = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
safe_mode = off
max_file_upload = 512M
max_post_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 300
```

***still failing to install plugin***

Comment: Maybe the server is disalowing the usage of php.ini and/or .htaccess files. Do you have something like cPanel so you can confirm these changes has been taken in account by the server ?

Comment: actually I installed the very same theme and plugins on another hosting company and the problem solved, now Im trying to make the host admin understand the problem and adjust the changes based on my needs, where too look at? I have Cpanel, yes, I did all my changes on Cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its related to host setting and the way they let you edit php.ini and .htaccess
their default values always overwrite to yours

change the hosting service is the solution I found and it worked for me